# anaconda numpy, theano and pymc3 installation on windows 10 64bit

Tags: python

As a beginner, I tried to install pymc3 on my surface pro 4/win 10 64bit, searched several information on the web and struggled with several problems. Now I want to share my experience and ask some questions.

***First***, I chose winpython 3.5.2.3Qt5 with python 3.5. However I faced collapse errors when I run the pymc3 start example Linear Regression model [enter link description here](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/getting_started.html):sometimes is "kernel died", sometimes is "ImportError: DLL load failed:initialization routine failed". To solve the problem I searched blogs/articles and found other people recommend anaconda with python 2.7 [enter link description here](http://datahans.blogspot.jp/2016/04/installing-pymc3.html). Also someone said theano 0.8.2 is just only support python 3.4, not 3.5. I guess there are some compatible issues to result in the collapse.
So at last I install anaconda 4.2 64bit with python 2.7.

**Questions 1**: Since from anaconda 2.5 MKL is free and auto installed, I tested the links between numpy and MKL according to some blogs.

1)

```
numpy.__config__.show()
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\include']
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:/Users/sejab/Anaconda2\\Library\\include']
```

but there is no mkl_intel_lp64 files in the anaconda folder. **Does it not matter?**

2)`id(numpy.dot) == id(numpy.core.multiarray.dot) >> True`
someone said if they are linked, numpy should use numpy.core._dotblas. **Does it means numpy dot also use the multiarray rather than MKL blas in the environment?**

In a word, **is numpy automatically link with MKL in anaconda?**

***Second***, Theano is a special package as it need c/c++ and cuda compile configuration. Because my laptop doesn't have Nvidia GPU, I only need to concern c/c++ compile environment. Official theano installation guide and many articles/blogs suggest that first use `conda install mingw libpython`
and then git. However, I found`conda install theano`have already included mingw64 (may be TDM-GCC 64?) component and libpython. So I just run the command to install theano and thought it enough. Then I put the path of g++ to system path
(in my environment, it is

> "C:\Users\sejab\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\bin",  "C:\Users\sejab\Anaconda2\Library\mingw-w64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin"
>   and corresponding "include“ path).

To verify the installation, use the test program

```
import numpy as np
import time
import theano
A = np.random.rand(1000,10000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
B = np.random.rand(10000,1000).astype(theano.config.floatX)
np_start = time.time()
AB = A.dot(B)
np_end = time.time()
X,Y = theano.tensor.matrices('XY')
mf = theano.function([X,Y],X.dot(Y))
t_start = time.time()
tAB = mf(A,B)
t_end = time.time()
print("NP time: %f[s], theano time: %f[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)" %(np_end-np_start, t_end-t_start))
print("Result difference: %f" % (np.abs(AB-tAB).max(), ))
```

It's OK. `Result difference: 0.000000`.

***Third***, I follow the instruction on the official manual installation guide and other blogs,

1) downloaded precompiled *OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32.zip* and extract into c:\, put its bin and include path into system path;

2) Create a .theanorc.txt in the root

> C:\Users\sejab

and write into

```
[global]
device = cpu
floatX = float64

[blas]
ldflags = -LC:/OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32/bin -lopenblas
```

to config the oopenblas with theano. Run the test above again,

`NP time: 0.431000[s], theano time: 0.307000[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)
Result difference: 0.000000`.

If `floatX = float32`, the `Result difference` is not 0.

**Question 2**: is there another way to verify the link between theano and openblas? The test CPU time is change even fix the value of Matrix A, B.

**Question 3**: in the test, is theano automatically use multicore? If not, how to config it?

***Finally***, I used `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3` to install pymc3. It showed no problem to solve the same Linear Regression model in pymc3 official tutorial.

It's a little long, but I hope it can help others.